# How to create AWS glue worklflow (without using console) with different steps and configuration?

Tags: aws-glue

I want to create glue pipeline (workflow) without using console which will have all the steps need to run and also it will have details about the AWS resources.

Is there way to create it programmatically?

Comment: have you tried boto3 framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the workflow manually from the UI on the workflow page: https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/glue/home?region=us-east-2#etl:tab=workflows;workflowView=workflow-list